# How to hide the other items completely when I use "pause" operation in beamer?

Tags: beamer, itemize

When I compiling the following codes：

```
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item a
    \pause
    \item b
    \pause
    \item c
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

It's effect is the following:

[image: item with pause operation]

As we can see that when "a" appears we can also see "b" and "c". I want to know how to hide "b" and "c" completely?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: @Andrew I used an author kit and I was not sure how the effect is controlled. From the answer, I've known it is controlled by \setbeamercovered. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should have been comment but there this can't be put.

This hides them

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item a
    \pause
    \item b
    \pause
    \item c
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

It won't if you uncomment the line

```
%\setbeamercovered{transparent}
```

Comment: Superb. For so long I was searching for this. It works for me .